Fill down from a specific row based on criteria
I have a table below with a list of transactions for each policy. One of the rows for each policy has a 'Y' as being a policy that had a certain 'issue'. I would like to create a new column to mark the row for 'Y' and the rows following for the same policy with a 1.
Basically for each policy, an issue occurred at some stage within the life cycle of the policy and I want to identify the PolicyVersion which is marked as a 'Y' and any subsequent rows for the same policy after the row marked 'Y'.
I can't quite figure out the correct partition



PolicyNum
TransactionDate
PolicyVersion
IssueFoundOnThisVersion
DesiredResult




A12345
2023-01-01
1
N
0


A12345
2023-06-01
2
Y
1


A12345
2023-07-01
3
N
1


A12345
2024-08-01
4
N
1


A12346
2023-02-01
1
N
0


A12346
2023-03-01
2
N
0


A12346
2023-07-01
3
N
0


A12346
2023-08-01
4
Y
1


A12346
2024-01-01
5
N
1




We can use SUM() as a window function here:
SELECT
    PolicyNum,
    TransactionDate,
    PolicyVersion,
    IssueFoundOnThisVersion,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN IssueFoundOnThisVersion = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNum ORDER BY PolicyVersion) > 0
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DesiredResult
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    PolicyNum,
    TransactionDate;

The SUM() logic above does a rolling sum, per policy, incrementing by one each time there is an issue with a certain policy.

ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING would be wise, in case of duplicates in the ordering, it's also more efficient (at least in SQL Server). Also if OP wants a 1 even in the event of multiple Y values in the same partition then you'd need to cast the result to bit to get it correct.

@Tim thanks so much, that's working exactly as I'd hoped, cheers
